# Bluetooth low energy advertisment packet format android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-4.3-jelly-bean

device broadcast a advertisement packet consist of byte array in onLeScan method which contain device name and current temperature (know from the ios app) but how to convert byte array which contain ble device name and temperature. i didn't find any format of broadcast data please any body know please tell me.
in ios it easy nsdictionary format ontain key and value which contain name and temperature in hex format. i just try to convert byte array in string i get name but other are garbage character are printed so how did i extract ble name and temperature value from byte array

Comment: The broadcast format is dependent to the device. You should ask the hardware maker.

Comment: One more thing, I think I have seen a page in bluetooth.org describing all the possible advertising data format for BLE, but I cannot find it now. If you can get that reference, and from the iOS version you can deduce what the byte array is representing by yourself.

Comment: The data portion of an LE advertising packet is in the EIR data format.  Do search for "bluetooth le extended inquiry response data format" or look at the core 4.0 bluetooth specs pg 1690.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Tisdall it work's thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured I should make this a regular answer...

The data portion of an LE advertising packet is in the EIR data format. Do search for "bluetooth le extended inquiry response data format" or look at the core 4.0 bluetooth specs pg 1690.